# How to get value of toString methods from subclasses into another class, and iterate them through for-loop to add the value into one string?

Tags: java, subclass, tostring

So I've got 4 subclasses which extend DessertItem Class with toString() methods:

```
//candy

     public String toString() {
         String line1 = String.format("%-25s$%",super.getName());
         String line2Pt1 = String.format("%-16.2flbs%@-8.2/f.:%", candyWeight, pricePerPound);
         String line2Pt2 = String.format("%-6f", calculateCost());
         String line2Pt3 = String.format("[Tax: $%.-4f]", super.calculateTax());
         String outputVar = String.format("%s\n\t%-45s%s%17s", line1, line2Pt1, line2Pt2, line2Pt3);
         return outputVar;
     }

//cookie
     public String toString() {
         String line1 = String.format("%-25s$%",super.getName());
         String line2Pt1 = String.format("%-16.2flbs%@-8.2/f.:%", cookieQty, pricePerDozen);
         String line2Pt2 = String.format("%-6f", calculateCost());
         String line2Pt3 = String.format("[Tax: $%.-4f]", super.calculateTax());
         String outputVar = String.format("%s\n\t%-45s%s%17s", line1, line2Pt1, line2Pt2, line2Pt3);
         return outputVar;
     }

//icecream
    public String toString() {
         String line1 = String.format("%-25s$%",super.getName());
         String line2Pt1 = String.format("%-16.2dscoops%@-8.2/f.:%", scoopCount, pricePerScoop);
         String line2Pt2 = String.format("%-6f", calculateCost());
         String line2Pt3 = String.format("[Tax: $%.-4f]", super.calculateTax());
         String outputVar = String.format("%s\n\t%-45s%s%17s", line1, line2Pt1, line2Pt2, line2Pt3);
         return outputVar;
        }

//Sundae class which extends IceCream class
     public String toString() {
         String line1 = String.format("%-25s$%",super.getName());
         String line2Pt1 = String.format("%-16.2sTopping: %@-8.2/f.:%", toppingName, toppingPrice);
         String line2Pt2 = String.format("%-6f", calculateCost());
         String line2Pt3 = String.format("[Tax: $%.-4f]", super.calculateTax());
         String outputVar = String.format("%s\n\t%-45s%s%17s", line1, line2Pt1, line2Pt2, line2Pt3);
         return outputVar;
     }
```

Also, I have got another class - Order, in which I would like to get toString() method values:

```
 public String toString() {
     String finalOutput = "";
     finalOutput += "------------------------Receipt-------------------";

     for() {
```

So, my question is How do I access the toString values from sublasses, and then how do I ittereate through them, so I can add the value into my finalOutput variable?

Comment: Where do you have the instances of the 4 classes? You need an instance to access a method

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class:

```
    public abstract class ToMyString
    {
        public abstract String toString();

        private static ArrayList<ToMyString> ivClasses = new ArrayList<>();

        public ToMyString()
        {
            super();
        }

        protected void addClass( ToMyString aClass )
        {
            ivClasses.add( aClass );
        }

        protected String[] getToStrings()
        {
            String[] toStrings = new String[ivClasses.size()];
            int index = 0;

            for (ToMyString aClass : ivClasses)
                toStrings[index++] = aClass.toString();

            return toStrings;
        }
    }
```

Then for each of the classes you want the toString for:

```
    public class SomeClass extends ToMyString
    {
        private SomeClass()
        {
            super();

            addClass( this );
       }
   }
```

And finally to get the toString(), from ANY of the classes which extend `ToMyString`:

```
         for (String aString : getToStrings())
                process(aString);
```

Comment: Shoot, forgot, your `DessertItem` class would extend `ToMyString`, which means its sub-classes would inherit `ToMyString`.